# How to show that $|(1+ia)/(1-i/a)| = a$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, absolute-value

I'm struggling to show, that:

$$\Bigg| \dfrac{1+\mathrm{i}\cdot a}{1+\mathrm{i}/a} \Bigg| = a \;.$$

($\mathrm{i} $ denoting the imaginary unit, $a$ is a real, postive number)

Is there some simple trick I'm missing or any theorem helping to show, that this equation is true?

Comment: @Arthur, yes, I missed to add this.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $1+$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $\left| \frac{1-\mathrm{i}\cdot a}{1-\mathrm{i}/a} \right|$ is the same number, as long as $a$ is real, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Note that if $a$ is a positive real number then
$$|1+ia|=\sqrt{1+a^2}\quad\text{and}\quad |1+i/a|=\sqrt{1+1/a^2}.$$
Moreover, recall that $|z/w|=|z|/|w|$ for any $z,w\in \mathbb{C}$ with $w\neq 0$.

Comment: I don't know why squaring both sides didn't came to my mind. You've been the fastest, I accept as soon as possible.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Squaring the two sides makes it easier to work with because it gets rid of square roots, but it isn't neccesary to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$1+i/a=i/a\,(1-ia)$$ and 
$$
|1+ia|=|1-ia|.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\left|\frac{1+ia}{1+\frac ia}\right|=\frac{|1+ia|}{\left|1+\frac ia\right|} = \frac{\sqrt{1^2+a^2}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac1a\right)^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{1^2+a^2}{1+\left(\frac1a\right)^2}}$$

can you continue from here?